# Need Help Building Kibana on Local machine

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch, kibana-4

I am new to ELK stack completely and I have zero experience in web development. But I am right now starting to explore ELK stack and I want to build Kibana locally on my machine and later contribute to it. It would be really glad if someone can guide me on how to build it locally.I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The detailed instructions on how to build kibana are in the [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#development-environment-setup) document that you can find in the root directory of kibana sources.